# TRIMMEAN / Date difference / multiple conditions Formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I currently have a table with 3 columns:

status (C) (could contain: "filled", "closed", "open")

date created on (H)

filled on (I)

```
    C    |   ...   |    H    |    I    
_________|_________|_________|_________
 Status  |   ...   |Created on| Filled on 
---------|---------|---------|---------
 filled  |   ...   |  Date1  |  Date3
 closed  |   ...   |  Date1  |  Date4
 open    |   ...   |  Date2  |  Date4
```

I have about 6,000 rows (rows may change on a daily basis, that is why I do not provide a range in the formula)

From there I want to get the trimmean (0.1) value for the 'Filled on' date minus the 'Created on' date (expressed in days). I only want them to be considered if the status is "filled" and all 3 columns are not blank.

I tried multiple formulas such as this one: `=TRIMMEAN(DATEDIF(H:H,I:I,"d")IF(C:C,"filled",""))`

But I did not manage to get the right formula.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or

```
=trimmean(filter(I2:I-H2:H,C2:C="filled",I2:I<>"",H2:H<>""),0.1)
```

or

```
=trimmean(filter(datedif(H2:H,I2:I,"d"),C2:C="filled",I2:I<>"",H2:H<>""),0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=trimmean((filter(Sheet1!J2:J,NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!C2:C)),Sheet1!C2:C="filled",NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!H2:H)),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!I2:I)))),0.01)
```

Assumes data is in Sheet1. Change sheet name or remove sheet name as needed.